# AutoCompleteTextView won't retain its instance

Tags: android

**PROBLEM**

My `AutoCompleteTextView` won't retain its instance.
The `Fragment` that contains it have `setRetainInstance(true)` and its not on `backStack`.
Every single view(`Spinner`, `EditText`, `Checkbox`, `Switch`) in that `Fragment` but `AutoCompleteTextView` is restoring back to the state before orientation change.

What might be the problem here?

**CODE**

`AutoCompleteTextView` is a custom element so I am passing the code.

```
public class PostAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

public String containerId;

public PostAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    this.addTextChangedListener(new PostCodeTextWatcher());
    this.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6)});
    this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    this.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789-"));
}
```

Thanks for help.